# "Doch die Anzahl der Menschen, die tatsächlich regelmäßig ein Buch aufschlägt" - Why not "aufschlagen" (singular)

Tags: dative, grammatical-number

I don't know why "aufschlagen" in the sentence above is in singular. Also I think that it refers to "die Menschen", so that must be plural, because refering to "die Anzahl" with "ein Buch aufschlagen" doesn't make so much sense.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your analysis is right. Although grammatically correct, the sentence is semantically wrong, because it contains a referencing error.

The grammatical number of the verb in a relative clause is congruent with the grammatical number of the noun it refers to. Here, *aufschlägt* is singular, therefore, it can only refer to *die Anzahl*, which is singular, too:

- … *die Anzahl* …, die ein Buch *aufschlägt*.

However, this doesn't make sense. It's not a number that opens a book, but people do. When you want to refer to *Menschen*, which is plural, you must use the plural form of the verb, *aufschlagen*:

- … *Menschen*, die ein Buch *aufschlagen*.

Comment: I disagree with the reasoning in this post. Nouns like *Anzahl* always allow for a double interpretation: referring to a number (as in *die Anzahl wächst, sinkt, beträgt* etc.) or referring to a collective (as in *eine kleine Anzahl der Teilnehmer litt unter Übelkeit*; also without the genitive, *eine Anzahl litt …*).

Comment: My old Duden grammar (3rd ed 1987, Rn. 1428) acknowleges that both forms are used, but notes that "the plural is used mostly if the counted is used as an apposition with the same casus as the quantity" - as in "Die Anzahl Menschen". But that does not preclude the use of plural with the genitiv, especially if a [synesis](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructio_ad_sensum) is intended.

Comment: @David Vogt, das ist ein völlig anderes Thema. Hier geht es darum, worauf sich ein *Relativsatz* bezieht, und das hat nichts damit zu tun, ob *Anzahl* oder dergleichen Wörter als Kollektiva betrachtet werden oder nicht. Schau dir einfach ähnliche Beispiele an. Nach deiner Interpretation wären auch folgende korrekt: *„das Dutzend Autos, das alle nur herumsteht“* oder *„ein Stapel Bücher, der gelesen wurde“* oder *„die Zahl derjenigen, die heute Geburtstag hat“* Alle diese Beispiele halte ich für falsch!

Comment: Die Frage wäre, warum das falsch ist, wenn Sätze wie *ein Dutzend Männer sitzt auf Stühlen vor dem Eingang* in Ordnung sind. "Nur Menschen können sitzen, ein Dutzend kann nicht sitzen" (analog zu deinem *[i]t's not a number that opens a book, but people do*) scheint nicht zu funktionieren; insbesondere, da der Genitiv fehlen kann: *der Anteil, der ein Buch aufschlägt*.

Comment: @DavidVogt, umgekehrt: Die Frage ist eher, warum der logisch falsche Bezug in den anderen Fällen als richtig angesehen wird. Die Antwort lautet vermutlich: Weil es sich durch häufigen Gebrauch durchgesetzt hat. Allerdings ist es nicht meine Aufgabe, dieses Thema in dieser Antwort über den Bezug eines Relativsatzes zu erörtern. Denn Fakt ist doch, nun hoffentlich auch durch die ähnlichen Beispiele im vorherigen Kommentar belegt, dass es in diesem Falle falsch ist. Und da ich nichts Gegenteiliges behauptet habe, ist die Abwertung meiner Antwort nicht gerechtfertigt.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich für mich persönlich klingen deine drei Beispiele richtig, nur das erste wegen _alle_ nicht. Aber _ein Dutzend Autos, das komplett/in Gänze nur herumsteht_ klingt wieder OK.

Answer (score -1):

It’s singular because it agrees with the subject *die Anzahl,* which is singular.

I don’t agree with the other answer. Don’t take meanings of words always literally. Just because a number of people does something doesn’t mean it’s literally a number.

I can say: Ich sehe eine große Anzahl an …, but I obviously don’t intend to say that I see an actual number.

I myself would have phrased it just like the book.

Comment: -1 because in this example it is completely clear that they don't mean {a number of people} who {open a book}, but clearly a number of {people who open a book, each individually}. To use the wrong reference anyway is just indifferent use of language. "Ich sehe eine große Anzahl Enten" literally means that you see not only one duck, but many ducks, {you} see a {number of ducks}. Gerne: "Ich sehe einen Schwarm Fische, der unter der Oberfläche schwimmt." Aber sicher nicht: "Ich sehe eine große Anzahl Schäfchenwolken, die am Himmel steht."

Comment: I criticised the statement "It's not a number that opens a book, but people do,” independent of how you want to parse the noun phrase.

Comment: No, if you had only criticized that statement, I wouldn't have downvoted. You went on explaining that the "die" of the relative clause refers to "the subject *die Anzahl*" and talk about "a number of people doing something". Which leads to the discussion in my comment.

Comment: I’m talking about a collective (=not literally a number) that is doing something, shrinking.

Comment: I guess you think of it as a number falling, but it doesn’t say _die Anzahl […] fällt_, it says _wird kleiner._ A collective can shrink. I don’t think it is “completely clear.”

Comment: Anyway that really wasn’t supposed to be my main point, so sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm talking about the relative clause, about who regularly opens a book, not about what is shrinking. It's not the collective {the number of people} that opens a book, but the collective is defined by what their individual members do. That's what the question is about and that's my whole point.

Comment: A relative clause can be defining. _Das ist der, der hier das Sagen hat_. Oder _Das ist der Kommentar, auf den ich antworte._

Comment: No dissent there. Just not in this sentence, where the relative clause describes what an individual does, not what the collective does. The collective here is defined by what *its members* do.

Comment: I disagree. It makes sense both ways (define a collective consisting of members who do X, thus the collective will do X as well, or define a collective that does X, thus each member of said collective does X).